# does Azure not remove shut-down nodes from load balancing?

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer

I've got a load-balanced end-point being served by 2 vms, and I shut down one of them through the web interface, however it seems that the shut-down endpoint is still being included in the load-balancer rotation. Is this the case or am I missing a silly mistake on my part?

Comment: What do you mean by 'shut down one of them through the web interface' - did you scale down from 2 instances to 1?

Comment: He could also mean rebooting/reimaging one of the instances ...

Comment: I hesitate to call them instances because they don't share or overlay the same persistant storage - I mean they are two vm guests though...anyhoo, I found out that machines that are shut down are not removed from their endpoints. There is a powershell and REST api for manually adding/removnig endpoints (which obviously any production service is going to need) but where the REST api is documented..dunno.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about new "Windows Azure Virtual Machines" or "Web/Worker based VM"?

With Windows Azure Virtual Machine, you can create multiple separate Virtual Machines and use Powershell cmdlets "get-azurevm" with parameter "-LBSetName" to set probe Load balancing undersame -LBSetName setting as below:

```
get-azurevm -ServiceName "XXXX" -Name "XXX" | Set-AzureEndpoint -Name "HttpIn" -Protocol "tcp" -PublicPort 80 -LocalPort 80 -LBSetName "XXX" -ProbePort 80 -ProbeProtocol "http" -ProbePath "/" | Update-AzureVM
```

If you configured the Load Balancer and shutdown the instance, the Load Balancer will still shows all machines configured with probe.